# SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant

Tags: email, azure-devops, smtp

This error coming from my azure function when sending reply email. I have set scopes as below.

```
"scopes": [
      "offline_access",
      "email",
      "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
      "https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All",
      "https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send"
    ],
    "replyScopes": [
      "offline_access",
      "email",
      "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All",
      "https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All",
      "https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send"
    ],
```

In Azure Active directory I gave below persmion for my app.

- Mail.Read
- MAP.AccessAsUser.All
- Mail.Send
- SMTP.Send
- POP.AccessAsUser.All
- Mail.ReadWrite

But I am getting this error. Anyone have an idea to solve this.

Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information.

Comment: This is a living nightmare of an issue. For people who have no admin rights it is impossible to send emails via smtp... I have been struggling with this since April 2022...